# Чи можна так сказати, що корбочка криниці "набуває оберт"?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-russian, граматика, узгодження-слів

Чи можна так сказати, що корбочка криниці "набуває оберт"? Знайшла вираз "набирає (набуває) обертів", але мені потрібно, як російською "обретает оборот, вращение", тобто, як початок руху, а не збільшення кількості обертів.

Comment: Під *коробочкою* ви маєте на увазі [оце](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Коловорот_(простий_механізм))? Може *починає обертатись*. Було б добре бачити повне речення.

Comment: Так, це коловорот, корба, корбочка криниці.  Мені для вірша треба, тому бажано знати, чи можна так висловитись? Це і є все речення, як задано.

Comment: Я і думаю, що це канцелярщина *обретает оборот*, але якщо вірш, то це інше, звісно. У такому разі, заради рими, можна вільно використати щось аби було зрозуміло. Наприклад, *починає оберт/крут/рух* (очевидно, що рух тут обертовий, хіба його зламали).

Comment: Краще тоді візьму так: "починає оберт". Так ясніше буде.